# Best way to present nested data/grid in web mvc

Tags: model-view-controller, telerik, grid

What's is the best way to do this with CRUD? Nested grid/ master-detail, hierarchical data? Not sure how it was called but basically it looked like this:

**https://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxGridViewDemos/MasterDetail/MasterDetail
**

I've used telerik mvc grid for a while and I encountered some issues that I dont like to deal with again. Please suggest other ways that is free and easy to use.

Thanks